# How to get sum() by Column by Date in Kusto

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to have a report with a metrics of *sum* by *count* by some column by date in LogAnalytics.

So far I could use -

```
Perf
| summarize sum(CounterValue) by TimeGenerated, Computer
```

which gives me below result in screenshot. But I want in a format per day. Something like -

```
Date,Computer,sum_Count
01-17-2020,ABC,100
01-16-2020,ABC,132
01-17-2020,XYZ,700
01-16-2020,XYZ,800
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try using `startofday()`:

```
Perf
| summarize sum(CounterValue) by startofday(TimeGenerated), Computer
```

or `bin()`:

```
Perf
| summarize sum(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d), Computer
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting extra 12:00:00.000 AM - "1/9/2020, 12:00:00.000 AM". Can this be removed and only date part need to retain.

Comment: you can use [format_datetime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-datetimefunction) to format datetime values as you require